# Debugging empty space in triangle print - JS

Tags: javascript, algorithm, debugging

folks!

I'm getting a hang of how JS works, and I've started a "build a triangle" exercise. I've managed to get it working, but something else is bothering me. The triangle gets printed alright, but I can't seem to find a way to remove the empty spaces from the first line. Here's the code:

```
function triangle(n) {
    // JS needs this.
    let result = "";

    // Newline loop
    for(let newlines = 0; newlines <= n; newlines++) {
        // Space loop
        for(let spaces = (n - newlines); spaces > 0; spaces--) {
            result += " ";
        }
        // Hashes loop
        for(let hashes = 0; hashes < newlines; hashes++) {
            result += "#";
        }
        result += "\n"
      }
    console.log(result);
}
```

The result is coming like this:

```
 <empty line> 
     #
    ##
   ###
  ####
 #####
######
```

I'm not looking for a spot-on answer, but rather how do I debug this? Where is this newline being generated?

Appreciate the tips in advance!

Comment: The first set of loops generates 6 spaces and 0 hash marks.

Comment: Indeed it does! Thanks for the assistance!